# custom sts and authenticate to share point web application

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth

I have one requirement can  please take a look and guide me how to accomplish.

- i created a custom asp.net sts service as you told
- i created some claims (username,email,password)
- i want to make trust between sts and my sharepoint web application which is created by claims authentication enable.
- also i have one asp.net site which is using farms based authentication 
  when user login to asp.net application he can authenticated in asp.net and from here he want to view some sharepoint 
  pages which has some data from bi,

when user redirect to sharepoint how i can allow to hime view sharepoint pages

Comment: hi i written  one asp.net sts application  and when i make trust to sharepoint  web application it not work, i given hostname http:myportal/_trust

Comment: hi how to do this